# Exercicio de comando repetição for em python

Tags: python

O exercicio é esse aqui:

Marcílio e Aurélio estão disputando a eleição para presidente do Centro Acadêmico. Para ser
considerado vencedor, o candidato deve ter mais votos que seu opositor, e também uma
quantidade de votos superior ao total de votos brancos.
Escreva um programa que receba como entrada os votos de 100 alunos e exiba uma mensagem
informando o nome do eleito. Caso não haja nenhum vencedor, deverá ser exibida uma
mensagem informando que será necessária uma nova votação.

Eu tentei assim:

```
for cont in range(4):

     votosAlunos = str.upper( input("digite seu voto:"))

    if(votosAlunos == " Marcílio "):
        votosM = votosM + 1

    elif(votosAlunos == " Aurélio "):
        votosA = votosA + 1

    elif(votosAlunos == "Branco"):

        votosB = votosB + 1


    if(votosM > votosA) and (votosM > votosB):
       print("Marcílio")
    elif(votosA > votosM) and (votosA > votosB):
       print(" Aurélio")
    else: 
       print(" Nova votação")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo seu código tem alguns problemas além daquele for sem ser usado, a sua comparação de resultados tem um espaço antes do nome e ainda são em minúsculo, você simplesmente esqueceu que usou a função `str.upper()`, logo a comparação sempre daria errada.

```
votosAlunos = []
votosM = 0
votosA = 0
votosB = 0

for k in range(0, 99):      # Para 100 votos

    votosAlunos.append(str.upper(input("digite seu voto:")))    #Anexa na lista os votos

    if(votosAlunos[k] == "MARCÍLIO"):

        votosM = votosM + 1

    elif(votosAlunos[k] == "AURÉLIO"):

        votosA = votosA + 1

    elif(votosAlunos[k] == "BRANCO"):

        votosB = votosB + 1


if(votosM > votosA) and (votosM > votosB):
    print("Marcílio")
elif(votosA > votosM) and (votosA > votosB):
    print("Aurélio")
else: 
    print("Nova votação")
```